# ndb.get_multi() returning null entities

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I want to use `ndb.get_multi(list_of_keys)` to avoid doing queries which are more expensive. If my understanding is correct, `ndb.get_multi()` only charges you 1 read per entity returned, so if you have a list of 50 keys, and only 20 are found, you should only get charged for 20 reads.

```
        keys = list()

        keys.append(Key('User', 2)) // this user exists
        keys.append(Key('User', 12)) // this user DOES NOT exist
        keys.append(Key('User', 15)) // this user DOES NOT exist

        users = ndb.get_multi(keys)
```

What I get back is 3 items, 1 with a user, and 2 with just null values. When I check AppStats, I see that it does indeed charge me for all the keys I put in there, even though 2 did not exist.

Why am I getting null entities back? Shouldn't items not found just be skipped?

Comment: Looking at your other question and this one, you're barking up the wrong tree.  You're going to have to pay per entity returned.  Queries are pretty efficient.  If it's not doing what you want, you need to think of alternatives, like using projection queries or some sort of caching, like memcache, edge cache, or storing denormalized data in other entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to be able to do

```
obj1, obj2, obj3 = ndb.get_multi([key1, key2, key3])
```

If the number of results returned is of arbitrary length, the tuple unpacking breaks and you have to get a list and inspect and compare keys. It's also simple to remove None should you need it using [filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter):

```
filter(None, list)
```

The cost is per get/read (operation), which is not the same as per returned result (data). The cost of internal services and communications in GAE are roughly the same regardless of whether it exists, but you don't have to pay for cpu for deserialization for items that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

NO, because now you can see which items where NOT found.

Comment: You  are charged, because you look for them. The index is searched.

Comment: The nice thing about the datastore and its tools, is that you really know what is going on under the hood (costs) and with this information you can optimize. This is very important for scaleable applications. In SQL environments the query code is optimized, but not the costs of the query.